# using phpmailer on 1 button

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want to send mail with phpmailer using 1 button. Can you tell me how:

```
<?php

function send(){
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = 'myemail';                
$mail->Password = '******';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
$mail->Port = 465;                                  

$mail->setFrom('tryadi.tab@gmail.com', 'try adi');
$mail->addAddress('try.adi.baschara@gmail.com');     

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'email';
$mail->Body    = "email has been sent";
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
    $_SESSION['account_create'] = 'Akun Anda Telah Selesai Di Buat';
    header("location:index.php");
}
}
?>
```

and this for my submit code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>i</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me how to use 1 button for sending email? Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: what's problem with your code  where your facing issue

Comment: i just want to know how

Comment: can you tell me

Comment: <form action="mail.php" method="post" ><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>   in mail.php page if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ send(); }

Comment: mail.php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ send(); } where i input this

Comment: it didnt work can you answer in answer Question

Comment: didn't work mean . is there any error ?

Comment: now i have 1 issue

Comment: what the issue ?

Comment: SMTP connect() failed

Comment: did you replace all parameter with original values . like user name password

Comment: i did but still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your html to form like this and after submit check form submit using isset

```
  function  send(){
          .....
   }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ send(); } 

 <form action="mail.php" method="post" >
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is define a function - you need to actually call it, checking if the request is a form submission first:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    send();
}
//your send function definition goes here
```

You also need to define the `$email` variable - you're using it but never defining it.

Comment: Thank but smpt connect() failed

Comment: So search for that - there are literally hundreds of answers to that on here and in the docs.